# Using case when in an insert statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create some logic using an `case` in an insert

this is the code i am using but

```
elseif ( exists(select id from transactions where tel = last_inserted_number && secure_using_payslip IS NULL)) then
    update transactions set secure_using_payslip=last_inserted_message where 
     tel=last_inserted_number;

     insert into messageout(messagetext, messageto)
        values("you choose not to secure with payslip.", last_inserted_number),(case when last_inserted_message = 'no');

     insert into messageout(messagetext, messageto)
        values("you choose to secure with payslip.", last_inserted_number),(case when last_inserted_message = 'yes');

       insert into messageout(messagetext, messageto)
        values("Are you formally employed or self employed?.", last_inserted_number);
```

The code fails in.How should i use case here?.

Comment: Is this MySQL or PHP code?  It looks like a mix of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `CASE` expression into the value.

```
INSERT INTO messageout (messagetext, messageto)
VALUES (CASE last_inserted_message
            WHEN 'no' THEN "you choose not to secure with payslip."
            WHEN 'yes' THEN "you choose to secure with payslip."
            ELSE "Invalid choice."
        END, last_inserted_number);
```